# Javascript way of Kth Smallest Element in a Sorted Matrix

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

trying to solve  `Kth Smallest Element in a Sorted Matrix`,basically You found a solution with a memory complexity better than O(n2).

```
            Input: matrix = [[1,5,9],[10,11,13],[12,13,15]], k = 8
            Output: 13
            Explanation: The elements in the matrix are [1,5,9,10,11,12,13,13,15], and the 8th smallest number is 13
```

what is this code line doing please help me find out???

```
 mid = (lo + (hi - lo) / 2) >> 0;
```

Here is full code

```
            var kthSmallest = function(matrix, k) {
                var n = matrix.length, lo = matrix[0][0]
                var hi = matrix[n-1][n-1];
                var mid, count;
                
                while(lo < hi) {
                    mid = (lo + (hi - lo) / 2) >> 0;
                    count = countLEQ(matrix, mid);
                    if (count < k) {
                        lo = mid + 1;
                    } else {
                        hi = mid;
                    }
                }
                return lo;
            };

            var countLEQ = function (matrix, x) {
                var n = matrix.length;
                var count = 0;
                var j;
                
                matrix.forEach(function(row){
                    for(j = 0; j < n && row[j] <= x; j++){ ;}
                    count += j
                });
                return count;
            };
```

Am i right in saying Time complexity as `O(log n)` as its  `binary search algorithm` ???

Your help is appreciated

Carolyn

Comment: `([].concat.apply([], matrix)).slice(k-1, k)[0]`, or `matrix.flat(2).slice(k-1,k)[0]`.  Are you sure the input matrix is supposed to be sorted?  You don't even need `slice`.  `matrix.flat(2)[k-1]` works.

Comment: This line in regards to "what is this code line doing please help me find out" `mid = (lo + (hi - lo) / 2) >> 0;
` Looks like a part of a "binary search", akin to the guessing number game higher or lower. The code above is getting the "middle" value to keep searching. As such and if so, the data to search must already be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity is between O(log n) and O(n), since while the outer loop is indeed a binary search (O(log n)), the `countLEQ` method is serial (O(n)).

This line:

```
mid = (lo + (hi - lo) / 2) >> 0
```

Just calculates a new mid point, truncating any fractions.  Shift right `>> 0` does this by converting to int.  This is usually done using the double tilde operator (`~~`): i.e. `mid = ~~(lo + (hi - lo) / 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
mid = (lo + (hi - lo) / 2) >> 0
```

This is used for calculating the mid index in a binary search. It is avoiding any fraction values.

Alternative Method for calculating mid index in a binary search :

```
Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2)
```